# Django and Keystrokes dynamics as authentication

Tags: django, authentication, keystroke

How do i capture and use keystrokes dynamics as my second factor authentication in Django web application project?

I have implemented the normal username and password authentication in Django and fails to know how i can use keystrokes to add it for authentication.